# How do i make a variable global over different .py files

Tags: python, global

Im trying to use a pandas dataframe in a function in a different .py file then where the DF is instantiated. I tried using global, but that only seems to work within the same file.

Would someone be so kind to point me towards the direction I can find a solution in?

Cheers!

Comment: What is the kind of the variable, type? exemple?

Comment: Your variable would need to be imported into the other files. They won't be automatically imported even if they are global

Comment: You don't; Python doesn't have program-wide globals, only module-level globals.

Comment: Why not just import it?